# The usage of ''the only'' usage on a sentence

Tags: word-usage

Is this sentence correct?

> The only countries from South America that I know are Mexico, Brazil and Argentina.

Is not 'the only' meant for just only only one?

Comment: Your sentence is grammatically correct but it is not geographically correct – Mexico is not part of South America.

Answer (score 1):

This is totally normal usage - because 'countries' is (massively) plural, it is obvious to a native speaker that a short list still fits the definition of 'only a few'.

Answer (score 1):

Your example is fine. It is perfectly good idiomatic English to use "the only" to list one or more of a larger set. So your sentence is correct although it may be better to change the preposition:

> The only countries **in** South America that I know are Mexico, Brazil
>   and Argentina.